# Highcharts error #13 for react app with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I have a question which is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629013/how-to-use-highcharts-in-typescript-and-react) topic. I am new to TS and React and created an app according to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter) guide. However, when I try to add a highchart in App.tsx as follows:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";

let myChart = Highcharts.chart("App",{
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
});

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="App">
          {myChart}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

What happens is, when running npm run start, I get the following error. What am I missing?

```
Error: Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13
▶ 9 stack frames were collapsed.
./src/App.tsx
D:/Programming/Bitbucket/report-example/src/App.tsx:5
  2 | import './App.css';
  3 | import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
  4 | 
> 5 | let myChart = Highcharts.chart("main",{
  6 |     chart: {
  7 |         type: 'bar'
  8 |     },
View compiled
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
./src/index.tsx
D:/Programming/Bitbucket/report-example/src/index.tsx:1
> 1 | import * as React from 'react';
  2 | import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  3 | import App from './App';
  4 | import './index.css';
View compiled
▶ 6 stack frames were collapsed.
```

**EDIT:**

I have figured out a way to get it working. But I am still having two questions regarding this solution:

1) Why does it work with componentDidMount?

2) Can I somehow define the chart outside the App class such as above with let?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";

class App extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [1, 0, 4]
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 7, 3]
            }]
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="container">loading </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/errors/13: "This error occurs if the chart.renderTo option is misconfigured so that Highcharts is unable to find the HTML element to render the chart in." You are trying to render in a div called `main` but that div does not exist.

Comment: My bad, even though this is not the issue as the error still exists. I have edited the code.

Comment: Do you mean I have to change the div name to anything else than app or introduce a new div? Could you give a small example?

Comment: Look at the live example they gave in the answer you linked: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hmzrag?file=index.html. You can see they have index.html with the `main` div in it.

Comment: I can see the relationship in the example. But I am using a different file setting, such that there is no index.html. As far as I understand the html part is within the class App as shown above. And the div name is the same as stated in the highcharts render to option.